# Create message box

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a message box with a little piece on the side of it. Like this:

[image]

I was able to implement it (with a hack, I'll explain later) with solid colors. If the message box has transparency (alpha) applied to it, then the hackish part starts to appear. Which then looks like this:

[image]

As you can see in the second image, the extra piece overlaps the actual message. How can I 'cut' the overlapping extra piece, redesign the extra piece without overlapping the message box?

#### JSFiddle

```css
body {
  background-color: burlywood;
}
.about {
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.about::before {
  content: "";
  box-sizing: initial;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 25px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 43px;
  width: 53px;
  bottom: -4px;
  right: -78px;
  clip: rect(18px, 37px, 42px, 0px);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="about indent text-message-animation">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
</div>
```

**Edit**

In place of the burlywood background color there will be an image. So I can't just change the color to `border-color: #856e51;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do what you're asking with just CSS. This is why you typically see the "tails" attached to the edges instead of the corners when using rounded boxes.

You'll need an image or SVG to form the background. If you want the image/SVG to be dynamic, in that it resizes without distorting the corners, you'll need to arrange more complex HTML/CSS and provide either separate images or use in combination with something similar to a [9-patch graphic](http://wiresareobsolete.com/2010/06/9-patches/).

(If you're interested in the 9-patch approach, they are typically used on Android but there are [Javascript libraries](https://github.com/chrislondon/9-Patch-Image-for-Websites) that make them easier to use on the web.)

Comment: @Jessica It's an involved process. [This JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tepxhtjv/) implements your example using an SVG as a partial 9-patch. Hopefully it's enough to give you an idea of what things you'd need to research in order to implement this sort of thing on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Apply this color for this class `.about::before`

```
.about::before {
    border-color: #856e51;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o7df6egw/3/

Comment: In place of the burlywood background color there will be an image. So I can't just change the color to border-color: #856e51;

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your question. I need a fast and beautiful message box so I customized it and I used the same color to `border-color` of edge and `background-color` of message box.

with a right edge and left edge code:

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.right {
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: rgb(3, 160, 82);
    color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    margin: 50px;
}

.right::after {
    content: "";
    box-sizing: initial;
    border-color: rgb(3, 160, 82);
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 25px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 43px;
    width: 53px;
    bottom: -4px;
    right: -78px;
    clip: rect(18px, 37px, 42px, 0px);
    z-index: -1;
}

.left {
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: rgb(26, 26, 26);
    color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    margin: 50px;
}

.left::before {
    content: "";
    box-sizing: initial;
    border-color: rgb(26, 26, 26);
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 25px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 43px;
    width: 53px;
    bottom: -4px;
    right: -78px;
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
    left:-77px;
    clip: rect(18px, 37px, 42px, 0px);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
    <div class="right">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur molestiae recusandae iusto non autem! Corporis officia, unde sunt, necessitatibus voluptatum incidunt cum aperiam ipsam pariatur placeat earum vero fugit ipsum.
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur molestiae recusandae iusto non autem! Corporis officia, unde sunt, necessitatibus voluptatum incidunt cum aperiam ipsam pariatur placeat earum vero fugit ipsum.
    </div>
```